# Reproducir diferentes videos en un div sin recargar la pagina

Tags: html, mysql, css, video

necesito algo de ayuda, quisiera que desde una misma pagina pudiera reproducir varios videos, expico mejor en un div poner un reproductor y al lado varios botones que cada ves que oprima en el boton me carge el video de ese boton en el div sin tener que recargar la pagina, los enlaces de los videos estarian almacenados en una base de datos, no se por donde empezar, de ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata de hacer esto

Hora estoy cambiando el video de forma local con iframe de youtube, pero en tu caso puedes hacer el llamado con los datos que tienes en tu mysql

```js
function cambiar() { 
var urlvideo ="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QFfKEJcDO-8";
document.getElementById('video').src=urlvideo; 

}
```

```html
<div style='float:left;'>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wnJ6LuUFpMo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id='video'></iframe>

</div>
<button type='button' onclick='cambiar()'>SIGUIENTE VIDEO</button>
```

Espero que te funcione, un saludo

Comment: Me ffunciono perfecto muchas gracias, esto era lo que necesitaba